# Slow down data retrieval to preserve memory and avoid browser crash (PHP & SimplePie)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rss, simplepie

I'd like to build a RSS data retrieval process with PHP, MySQL, SimplePie, and jQuery, however I encounter problems with a crashing browser, limited server memory and error 500 when trying to retrieve and process a lot of data from external sources.

Is there a way to use jQuery (or another way) to "slow down" and "segment" the data retrieval and processing steps, i.e. can jQuery "split up" or "control" PHP output results into chunks, and force PHP to only process to the next remaining data retrieval chunk once the first has been finished, so that PHP has time to clear up server memory in between?

Basically my process is the following:

1. get source xml feeds from database (MySQLi WHILE loop)
2. initiate simplepie rss
3. FOREACH feed, get latest rss items (title, content, image, date, etc)
4. FOREACH rss item, check for images inside rss content element
5. FOREACH rss item, check external source html for more images (via file_get_contents)
6. check if images actually exist (getimagesize, get_headers)

Because I have a lot of FOREACH loops inside the MySQLi WHILE loop itself, the entire operation takes very long and is very memory intensive.

Example code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sources ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$feed_url = $row["feed_url"];

  $feed = new SimplePie();
  $feed->set_feed_url($feed_url);
  $feed->enable_cache(false);
  $feed->init();
  $feed->handle_content_type();

    foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 20) as $item){
    $link = $item->get_permalink();

    $homepage = file_get_contents($link);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($homepage);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $image_url = $tag->getAttribute('src');
       // process image further or return image here
    } // end foreach tag

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $image_url = $tag->getAttribute('href');
       // process image further or return image here
    } // end foreach tag

    ... more foreach loops here

  } // end foreach rss item

} // end mysqli while
```

Is there a way to use jQuery to return data back to AJAX throughout the FOREACH loops and "control" the remaining PHP loops so that the server is not overloaded?

Comment: Is there any reason you do not close the connection?  This may be a useful URL for an example.  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_close.asp   to release resources.

Comment: Yes I can close the connection after all mysqli while loops have been iterated, but this does not solve the issue of having so many things to calculate / output within these loops ....

Comment: What is the result of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sources ORDER BY id DESC; so we have some idea the number of rows you are returning?  Are you interested in tuning the MySQL instance?

Comment: Currently at development phase, there are about 10 sources total, but each RSS source returns about 10-20 RSS items. Getting all HREF and IMG links from the source HTML can easily reach about 50 URLs per source HTML, so we are speaking about hundreds to thousands of possible image URLs that need to be checked and processed. This will definitely grow much larger in the near future

Comment: Additional information request for tuning. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.